# Early return from a subscribe block in a function

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

I am new to JavaScript. I am trying to do an early return on error from a subscribe block.

This is what I have

```
public doSomething() {
   this.updateData(data)
     .subscribe((result) => {
                   // do something
                }, 
                (err) => {
                   console.error("Error");
                   return;
                   // require an early return from the block
                   // so rest of the function isn't executed. 
     });
   // do other work
}
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be:

```
public doSomething() {
   this.updateData(data)
     .subscribe((result) => {
                   // do something
                   // do other work
                }, 
                (err) => {
                   console.error("Error");
                   return;
                   // require an early return from the block
                   // so rest of the function isn't executed. 
     });
}
```

But you can also use await with async:

```
public async doSomething() {
       const result = await this.updateData(data);
       if (!result) return;
       // do other things
         
}
```